# External volume monitoring in Digital Ocean

Tags: devops, digital-ocean, infrastructure, mounted-volumes

I need to monitor the external volumes that my digital ocean droplets are using however, it seems that digital ocean internal monitoring system does not support monitoring external volumes but only the if the disk utilization is beyond a threshold. Are there any external tools that I can use to monitor external volumes in digital ocean?